# Can we move an image in Azure to a different location (region) using UI/Command or through any other way?

Tags: image, azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli, az

I have an image,say in "UK South". I want to move it to say "East US", how can I do it ? Is there an AZ CLI command, some option on UI or any other way ? I already used "az image copy" but getting error.

Comment: What's the error when you use `az image copy`? Please show the error and your complete command including the parameters.

Comment: I don't have the source disk so it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

If so,  you could follow the steps below.

1.Create a storage account in the portal located in `East US` in the target resource group.

2.Navigate to the source image in the portal -> `Create VM`, after creating the VM, navigate to the VM -> `Disks` -> copy the OS disk name.

3.Make sure you have installed the [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.8.0) powershell module, then use the commands below to copy the disk to the storage as a `.vhd` file.

```
#Source Disk
$rgName ="xxxxx"
$location ="UK South"
$diskName ="<diskname copied in step 2>"

#Dest Blob
$destrgName ="xxxx"
$destlocation ="East US"
$deststorageAccountName ="<storage account name in step 1>"
$destdiskName ="destDisk.vhd" 
    
#Grant the read access for the disk
$sas =Grant-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName $rgName -DiskName $diskName -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read

$saKey =Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $destrgName -Name $deststorageAccountName
$storageContext =New-AzStorageContext –StorageAccountName $deststorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $saKey[0].Value

#Create a new container vhds2 in the storage account
New-AzStorageContainer -Context $storageContext -Name vhds2

#Start copy, my disk size is 30GB, just takes several minutes
Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer vhds2 -DestContext $storageContext -DestBlob $destdiskName
```

After a while, check the copy status, if the Status is Success, it means the copy completed.

```
Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState -Context $storageContext -Blob $destdiskName -Container vhds2
```

4.After doing the steps above, you already have the `.vhd` file in the blob, then you can create an image directly in the portal from the blob URL.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy. I could not try this since creating storage would require taking approval from client. We used Shared Image Gallery to have a workaround for the time-being.

Comment: @Chaitanya Yes, Shared Image Gallery is also a workaround.